# PostGIS Create Geography Column From Geometry Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I currently have a table with the following type format:

```
varchar | numeric | numeric | geometry
```

To add a geography column, the following query was executed:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN geography geography(POINT,4326);
```

And now the type format of the table looks like:

```
varchar | numeric | numeric | geometry | geography
```

The issue I've now run into is that I'm trying to populate the geography column with information based off the geometry column. I've tried:

```
UPDATE table SET geography = geometry::geography;
```

But I run into the following error:

> ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type

Is there a query that I'm missing that would be able to successfully populate the new geography column with a geography conversion from the geometry data found in the geometry column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a `point geography`, but the source column contains a `multipolygon geometry`.

If all of your data is `multipolygon`, create a `geography` of the proper type:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN geography geography(multipolygon ,4326);
```

If you have a mix of input, create a generic `geography` column:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN geography geography(4326);
```